# Como saber se uma sessão já existe em um sistema?

Tags: android, session, arquitetura-de-software, parse.com

Tenho um aplicativo onde o usuário só pode estar logado em um dispositivo ao mesmo tempo, como posso fazer essa restrição?

Eu utilizo o serviço do Parse.com, ele provê uma API para troca de dados entre um app e a nuvem.

Exemplo: Criei minha conta, realizei login em um dispositivo e o meu login ele fica salvo(no meu caso coloco em SharedPrefferences no android), sempre que abrir o app não precisa logar novamente, ou seja digitar login e senha. Caso o usuário passe seu login e senha para terceiros, e esses terceiros tentem acessar de outro dispositivo quero dizer que já existe uma sessão em X dispositivo, e bloquear o acesso do terceiro.

O mais correto seria criar uma tabela no webservice onde eu guardo as sessões e seto algo como true, se ele estiver ativo?

Caso tenha outras formas melhores, agradeço.

Comment: Depende do que voce se refere como sendo sessao. Seria cookie de sessao? Sessao de autenticacao em um sistema operacional? "Sessao" em um long-polling?

Comment: Criar um socket , quando o socket desconectar é que o cliente ficou off

Comment: Acredito que uma boa forma de fazer isso seria criando sessões do usuário no servidor. Por exemplo, logou, gerou um 'sessionid', e esse sessionId tem que ser passado em toda requisição feita, e o servidor verifica se esse sessionid é o válido.

Comment: Editei a pergunta

Comment: Você parou para pensar que se o celular do usuário for roubado, ele não vai conseguir se deslogar para poder acessar a conta por outro aparelho? Como pretende resolver isso, vai fazer o sessionid expirar depois de um tempo? Quanto tempo é tolerável que o usuário fique sem acesso à conta?

Answer (score 0):

Criar um socket entre o cliente e o servidor , quando o socket desconectar é que o cliente ficou off.

Do lado do cliente apenas crie um socket para comunicação.

Do lado do servidor, aguarde novos clientes se conectarem, para cada cliente conectado crie um thread, dentro da thread receba mensagens do cliente, dependendo da implementação quando lançar uma Exception ou uma mensagem `null` significa que o cliente esta off.

Comment: O aplicativo provavelmente consulta webservices, nesse caso é preciso implementar a autenticação do usuário para poder acessar esses webservices e não acrescentar comunicação por sockets, que tornaria as coisas mais complexas e aumentaria o consumo da bateria com os keepalives.

Comment: Exato @Piovezan

Comment: Hum, sim eu pensei nessa solução para ser valida apenas para nao permitir a mesma conta permanecer ativo em mais de um dispositivo ao mesmo tempo.  Foi isso que entendi a primeiro momento.

Comment: Pois da forma q o problema foi proposto ao meu ver não faria sentido passar a senha para alguem. Por isso entendi errado